# Helicopter Money: a tax on banks?

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, money-supply

[In this text](http://voxeu.org/article/helicopter-money-illusion-free-lunch) of voxEU, the author are trying to explain why helicopter money will not have it's expected effect. For that conclusion they try to explain the different schemes on how Central Banks pay on excess reserves to commercial banks.

The 1st graph they show is this one:

[image]

I'm having a hard time understanding how one interprets the graph, together with the explanatory text right below the figure. Can someone help me?

Also, if someone knows where they got their graphs, I would appreciate.

Comment: I did a Tineye reverse-search for the image, and found only two occurrences - that VoxEU post, and a Chinese translation of it that appeared three days later. Given who the authors are, and given that they've referenced their work, and not the charts, I infer that they created the charts themselves, with the data for the right panel of each being as indicated in the caption of each.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers thanks for the info. any help on the remaining part of the question? ;)